# about bubble sorting implementation

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I have below bubble sort implementation:

```
def bubbleSortArray(arr):
    arr_len =len(arr)
     
    for i in range(0,arr_len):
        for j in range(i+1, arr_len):
            if  arr[i]>arr[j]:
                tmp=arr[i]
                arr[i]=arr[j]
                arr[j]=tmp
 
    print(arr)
```

most of the bubble sort implementation I found are like below one. can anyone please explain what's issue with my above implementation comparing to below one? both time complexity are O(n2), right?

```
static void BubbleSortBasicOptimised(int[] dataSet)
{
    // loop n-1 times.
    for (int i = dataSet.Length - 1; i > 0 ; --i)
    {
        // keep track of whether items were swapped
        // for this iteration
        bool swapped = false;

        // for each loop, iterate through the first i
        // items (ie. the unsorted ones)
        for (int j = 0; j < i; ++j)
        {
            // if adjacent items need to be swapped
            if (dataSet[j] > dataSet[j + 1])
            {
                // swap them
                Swap(dataSet, j, j + 1);

                // indicate that we found a swap
                swapped = true;
            }
        }

        // if nothing was swapped, then we should
        // already have everything in order
        if (!swapped)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The "issue" is that your algorithm is not bubble sort.

Comment: See [Can someone explain to me what type of sort this is?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59321946/can-someone-explain-to-me-what-type-of-sort-this-is) and [What is this inefficient sorting algorithm with two loops that compares the element at each index with all other elements and swaps if needed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72063568/what-is-this-inefficient-sorting-algorithm-with-two-loops-that-compares-the-elem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your algorithm is exchange sort. It's often confused with bubble sort. In each pass (outer loop iteration), you compare the value at position `i` with all the values at higher positions, swapping when necessary. In bubble sort, you compare the values at positions `j` and `j+1`.

[See also.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40786409/whats-the-difference-between-exchange-sort-and-bubble-sort-are-they-the-same)

`BubbleSortBasicOptimised` is a bubble sort but going from right to left and with an optimization: checking whether any swap has occured in the current pass, and stopping if not.

A bubble sort going from left to right instead would take `i` from `0` to `dataSet.Length - 1` and `j` from `i+1` to `dataSet.Length - 1`.